# MongoDB: $graphLookup in reverse order

Tags: mongodb

I have the following dataset:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("asdasdasd..."),
  dependencies: {
    customers: [
      ObjectId("1..."),
      ObjectId("2...")
    ]
  }
}
```

I use "$graphLookup" to see all customers, that have a relation to each other.

```
db.getCollection('customers').aggregate([{
  $graphLookup: {
    from: "customers",
    startWith: "$dependencies.customers",
    connectFromField: "dependencies.customers",
    connectToField: "_id",
    depthField: "depth",
    as: "dependencies.customers",
    maxDepth: 5,
  }
}])
```

This works all fine. But now i want to look up the graph in reverse order. The last customer in the dependency tree have no other dependencies to other customers. Of cource, otherwise i wouldnt be the last customer in that tree.

Is it somehow possible to see all customers that have a dependency to the last customer in the tree?

e.g.
normal GraphLookup:
C1 => C2 => C3 => ...

reverse GraphLookup:
C3 => C2 => C1

Maybe i need to change the schema... but i dont know how.

Another option would be to store 2 different types of dependencies: parent, children. But this makes it necessary to do all changes twice: for the customer that have a dependency X in parent and for the customer that have dependency X in children.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a good solution for this?

Comment: sorry. until now: no

Answer (score 1):

Your data needs to indicate what kind of direction the relationship is (parent=>child or child=>parent for example). The way I've seen this done is by storing data within an array indicating  the relationship. For you, that would be like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("asdasdasd..."),
  dependencies: {
    customers: [
      ObjectId("1..."),
      ObjectId("2...")
    ],
    customersOf: [
      ObjectId("1..."),
      ObjectId("2...")
    ],
  }
}
```

That way you can traverse the data in each direction

```
// get customers
db.getCollection('customers').aggregate([{
  $graphLookup: {
    from: "customers",
    startWith: "$dependencies.customers",
    connectFromField: "dependencies.customers",
    connectToField: "_id",
    depthField: "depth",
    as: "dependencies.customers",
    maxDepth: 5,
  }
}])


// get customersOf (reverse direction)
db.getCollection('customers').aggregate([{
  $graphLookup: {
    from: "customers",
    startWith: "$dependencies.customersOf",
    connectFromField: "dependencies.customersOf",
    connectToField: "_id",
    depthField: "depth",
    as: "dependencies.customersOf",
    maxDepth: 5,
  }
}])
```